# If-else for null condition SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, livelink

I am going to create a livereport using three example inputs:

1. Document Start Date
2. Document End Date
3. Emp ID

These are 3 rows in the SQL table DocumentData.

What I want to reproduce is the following:

If the user does not put any value in "Emp ID" field, it should show all "Document Start Date" and "Document End Date". Otherwise, only values corresponding to that "Emp ID" should be shown.

It may be very simple but I still need the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this could be a solution:

```
-- should work perfectly
  select *
  from DocumentData
  where 
    case 
      when :emp_id is null then 1 -- attention :emp_id introduced in stead of emp_id
      when emp_id = :emp_id then 1
      else 0
    end = 1
```

The `:emp_id` should be the variable that comes from the application (the field that is being altered by the user). The `1` in the `case when` statement acts as a `true` condition.

Comment: I tried the above code but not working for me. it is giving null result in case of no input for emp id. But When I put specific emp id it shows all records irrespective of emp id

Comment: I think you're checking the wrong value; `when :emp_id is null then 1`? But This seems to be a more complicated version of Bohemian's logic anyway.

Comment: I agree with @AlexPoole It is not what I need and complex form of below answer.

Comment: some how the logic working exactly the other way around, I ajusted the code once more, perhaps it works better now

Comment: in the end you could also write a where clause that is less complicated end states something like ... `where nvl(:emp_id, 1) in (emp_id,1)`

Comment: Not sure if it is working for you. But I tried and still getting same results. No success.

Comment: Are you sure that the variable that comes from the application is linked to the variable (`:emp_id` or on the other example `$emp_id`) the correct way? I have the impression that somehow the applicatioan literal is not passed through to the query (...)

Comment: Can you debug it in some way ... and print or log the variable that you use as input.

Comment: Hey @Shekhar-Sharma. I put some extra effort in it and tried the option with the where clause myself. Its works fine for me and exactlyt as you wanted it to be. See this link => [emp.doc](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6qKZQuBzrlNNUtEOXBQSi16RVE/view?usp=sharing).   This statement:
======================================
`select *
 from DocumentData
 where nvl(:emp_id, 1) in (emp_id,1)`

works fine. You will see that wen you enter - for example - 40 you retrieve only emp_id with "40". When you enter null, you will retrieve the whole data set.

Comment: I altered the case when statement in the original answer too. I forgot to introduce an **:emp_id** in the first case when statement. Should work perfectly now.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `OR` and pass the value to the query twice.

In generic query code (not knowing how livelink makes calls)

```
SELECT * FROM DOCUMENT
WHERE CREATED_DATE BETWEEN $startDate AND $endDate
AND (EMP_ID = $empId OR $empId IS NULL)
```

Comment: Getting same result as above answer. When empid fill input is not there then it shows no result and when I put value it shows all results for emp id + null results.

Comment: What actual value is provided for `empId` when the user doesn't enter anything? Could it be a blank string (rather than null)? If so, try `(EMP_ID = $empId OR $empId = '')` instead